# AC voltage ramp LabVIEW

Tags: labview, nidaqmx

I am totally new to LabVIEW. My purpose is to create an AC voltage ramp using this programming language like the one showed below. For example, I would like to change the voltage from 0 to 5 V in 2 seconds. How do I do that?

[image: "voltage form of standard ramp up supply": graph showing a supply voltage that starts at 0 and oscillates increasing, ending oscillating between -1 and 1 after 2 seconds]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to generate a signal with a DaqMX output board.
You should separate your problem in two parts: create waveform and "write" output in the DaqMX output board.

The AC voltage ramp is not a "canonic" waveform. So you should build your signal as follow:
y = sin X ramp.
For sin, use [this](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvanls/sine_wave/)
For ramp, you can simply use a growing number (for this use a for o while loop).

The created signal should be applied in the output boards by using the DAQmx VIs. See examples installed in your LabVIEW. There are different approaches to generate output with a DAQmx: single sample, single wavform, repetitive waveforms, ecc. Choose the most suited way for you application.